# Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access Twitter API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web, twitter

I'm developing a web application that uses the [Twitter API REST](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public). I have a page with Twitter accounts and a button for adding a new account. When the button is pressed, the function in the Angular controller is executed:

```js
// Calls token to add a new Twitter user
    $scope.callToken = function () {
        $http.get('/token')
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    };
```

This is the code in the backend to serve de request. It simply redirects to Twitter to add a new user.

```js
// routes.js
var token = express.Router();

 token.route('/token')
  .get(cuentasCtrl.getToken);
    
// Account file

exports.getToken = function(req, res) {

 twitter.getRequestToken(function(err, requestToken, requestSecret) {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send(err);
        else {
            _requestSecret = requestSecret;
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.redirect("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=" + requestToken);
        }
    });
};
```

But I get the next error:

```
Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access Twitter API
```

My server is running on localhost:3000 and If I put localhost:3000/token in my browser there is no problem. I have read  the solutions for [using CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-adding-cors-support-to-the-server) and tested other browsers but it hasn't worked for me. What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The redirect you are sending in your express response is caught by the http client you use in the frontend and the redirect happens there. You are in a classical CORS situation and of course this is not how you can interact with the Twitter rest APIs.

You have to make http calls to Twitter on the node side (server to server) or use a client side client library for Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript)

Comment: I think that the best way is doing the http on the node side, because I don't want the things that are included in the link. Only I want to get the Twitter token to interact with the user API REST.